# Finding a min value among non-numeric columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, min

Consider the following dataframe:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import pandas as pd # version 0.23.4
x_df = pd.DataFrame([[1.2, 3.4, 'n', 'a'], [5.6, 'a', 'b', 7.8], 
                    [2.2, 'c', 1.35, 'd'], ['k', 'o', 'b', 'c']], 
                    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I'm trying to achieve, the min value for each row (like below):

```
x_df =        A    B     C    D     min
         0  1.2  3.4     n    a    1.2
         1  5.6    a     b  7.8    5.6
         2  2.2    c  1.35    d    1.35
         3    k    o     b    c    nan
```

I tried to do this using:

```
x_df['min'] = x_df.apply(lambda x: x.min(numeric_only=True), axis=1)
```

However this throws an error:

```
NotImplementedError: ('Series.min does not implement numeric_only.', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using `for` loops or lengthy code?

If this question has already been answered, kindly point me and sorry for duplicate (search didn't get me what I wanted !)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is first  convert to numeric using `to_numeric` , leave the one can not be converted as `NaN` , then do `min`

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce',axis=1).min(1)
Out[96]: 
0    1.20
1    5.60
2    1.35
3     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer